# Docker-compose Nginx multiple containers flask issue

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose

I have a Flask app with a Nginx reverse proxy setup with docker-compose. I can get everything to work in a single container without problems, but I need to launch the staging and production servers on the same machine, so I am trying to migrate my setup to multiple containers with a separate nginx-proxy container. The reverse proxy setup seems to be ok, but when I access the app using the proxy Flask has some issue with the request. I detail below the docker-compose files and the server outputs.

#### NGINX-PROXY docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
```

#### Flask docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  # other services defined, not relevant for the issue

  data-api:
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development
      VIRTUAL_HOST: app.local
    build: ./dataAPI
    expose: 
      - 5000
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
     - ./dataAPI:/dataAPI
    networks:
      - nginx_proxy

networks:
  nginx_proxy:
    external: true
```

I added a line in `/etc/hosts` for `app.local`.
I spin up first nginx then the app. If I try to access it directly with `0.0.0.0:5000/staging/data` the request is served without problems, but if I try to use the proxy with  `app.local/staging/data` the Flask  app throws a 404:

#### Flask log

```
data-api_1  | 172.20.0.1 - - [30/May/2019 14:13:29] "GET /staging/data/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
data-api_1  | 172.20.0.2 - - [30/May/2019 14:13:31] "GET /staging/data/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you put the containers on the same network.  The nginx_proxy is using a network named `proxy` while the flask container is using an network named `nginx_proxy`.

By the way, docker-compose is useful for composing applications requiring multiple containers.  Rather than use a separate docker-compose file for each container, this setup might be easier if you put both services in the same docker-compose file.  Then you don't even need to setup a separate network as compose creates a default network for the services.

Another note, since you are using an nginx reverse proxy, you probably wouldn't want to map the flask port to the host machine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. the `proxy` network is defined inside a nginx directory, therefore it is called `nginx_proxy`. They are indeed in the same network, otherwise the request would not be forwarded to the flask app (see flask log). But for some reason, when the request is proxied the flask app returns a 404 instead. I want to run the exact same service as dev/production on the same machine, from what I found in other posts this should be the way to do it.